# Eclipse set 'default' LogCat Saved Filter

Tags: eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

I have a number of "Saved Filters" set up in Eclipse "LogCat" tab. The one that I want to see the majority of the time is in the middle of the list. Whenever I run my application, however, Eclipse will automatically change the LogCat view to the last Saved Filter. This is annoying as I then have to click the filter I want. Is there a way set a Saved Filter as the "default" so that is the one that is use when I run my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally. Under Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Logcat I found "Monitor Logcat for messages from applications in workspace." Unchecking that will stop Eclipse from automatically generating, and then switching to, a new "Session Filter" under the Logcat Saved Filters when you run the application.

This has the happy result of *not switching* to a different Logcat Saved Filter when you run your application. Whatever filter is selected will still be selected when running the application, thereby eliminating the need to constantly click back to the filter you want.

[image]